# Change redirection when session expires on Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

While logged in, **when session expires** and try to access a page that requires a user logged in, **Joomla redirected automatically to login form**.

How can I modify that redirect to establish that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom redirect in Joomla! back-end Components->Redirects

Comment: Is there a more elegant solution?